# Matplotlib animate subplots (2 hist and 2 scatter plots)

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

How can I animate the following 4 subplots? So far I've managed to make the animation not stop at all or to make the frames appear but not the dots/bars of the plots. I tried to follow this https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/subplots.html example but "subclassing" is far ahead of my skills.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# generate 4 random variables  
x = np.random.normal(-2.5, 1, 10000)
y = np.random.gamma(2, 1.5, 10000)
a = np.random.exponential(2, 10000)+7
b = np.random.uniform(14,20, 10000)

n_bins = 100
n = 100
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2, sharex='col')

# plot
ax1.hist(x, bins=n_bins, facecolor='c')
ax1.set_title('normal')
ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax1.tick_params(bottom=False, left=False)

ax2.hist(y, bins=n_bins, facecolor='c')
ax2.set_title('exponential')
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax2.tick_params(bottom=False, left=False)

ax3.scatter(x, a, facecolor='c')
ax3.set_title('gamma')
ax3.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax3.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax3.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax3.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax3.tick_params(bottom=False, left=False) 

ax4.scatter(y, b, facecolor='c')
ax4.set_title('uniform')
ax4.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax4.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax4.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax4.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax4.tick_params(bottom=False, left=False)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: what do you want to animate here? which variable do you want to vary?

Comment: the 4 variables defined at the start. I want to show their accumulation in each plot. Bars and dots accumulating over time. Is that not possible?

Answer (score 0):

in this line

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2, sharex='col')
```

ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, there are spaces for images
you need to create a image and put in ax1/2/3/4

i make a example that show [how to work with a matplot](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GoX8Fyq34RKC2ZrA8kBRtqgE9JmE3uE_?usp=sharing)

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand your solution. I do not want to put someth in the space, I already have the plots. I need to animate them.

Answer (score 0):

I understood after your comment about what you wanted to accomplish, to get a much more polished animation than what I am providing here would require planning out some math.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# some parameter to vary
vary = np.linspace(10, 120, 100, dtype=int)

n_bins = 100
n = 100
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex='col')


def plot_prop():
    # plot
    ax1.set_ylim(0, 350)
    ax1.set_title('normal')
    ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax1.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
    ax1.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    ax1.tick_params(bottom=False, left=False)

    ax2.set_ylim(0, 450)
    ax2.set_title('exponential')
    ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax2.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
    ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    ax2.tick_params(bottom=False, left=False)

    ax3.set_xlim(-7, 2)
    ax3.set_ylim(5, 25)
    ax3.set_title('gamma')
    ax3.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax3.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax3.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
    ax3.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    ax3.tick_params(bottom=False, left=False)

    ax4.set_xlim(0, 20)
    ax4.set_title('uniform')
    ax4.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax4.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax4.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
    ax4.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    ax4.tick_params(bottom=False, left=False)


for i, p in enumerate(vary):
    # generate 4 random variables
    x = np.random.normal(-2.5, 1, p * 100)
    y = np.random.gamma(2, 1.5, p * 100)
    a = np.random.exponential(2, p * 100) + 7
    b = np.random.uniform(14, 20, p * 100)

    plot_prop()
    ax1.hist(x, bins=n_bins, facecolor='c')
    ax2.hist(y, bins=n_bins, facecolor='c')
    ax3.scatter(x, a, facecolor='c')
    ax4.scatter(y, b, facecolor='c')

    plt.savefig('../imgs/img' + str(i) + '.png')
    ax1.cla()
    ax2.cla()
    ax3.cla()
    ax4.cla()

fig = plt.figure()
ims = []
for i in range(100):
    im = plt.imshow(plt.imread('../imgs/img' + str(i) + '.png'), animated=True)
    ims.append([im])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=200, blit=True)
ani.save('../imgs/animation.mp4', writer=animation.FFMpegFileWriter(), dpi=300)
```

Here is a [link](https://github.com/logicatcore/share_point/blob/master/animation.mp4) to the animation I've got

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. The code does nothing in VSC and the link does not work, it says that "sorry we cannot display such laurge files".

Comment: Github doesn't play mp4 files so you need to download but you don't have to if you run the code for yourself and for the code to function, you need to change `plt.savefig(where you want to save)` and `plt.imread(from where you want to read)`